# Evaluate subtraction inside GitLab CI VARIABLES keywords

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

I am trying to parallelize flutter build using GitLab using GitLab's [`parallel`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallel) keyword and flutter's  `--total-shards` and `--shard-index`.

Something like below

```
test_job:
  stage: test
  parallel: 3
  script:
   - flutter test --total-shards $CI_NODE_TOTAL --shard-index $CI_NODE_INDEX
```

However, this script fails in the last job because off-by-one error `$CI_NODE_INDEX > $CI_NODE_TOTAL`. Seems like it is undocumented that `$CI_NODE_INDEX` starts from 1 instead of 0.

I wanted to subtract the variables by using `VARIABLES` to `$CI_NODE_INDEX_ZERO` because the variable is being used multiple times throughout this long job (the script in the example above is shortened).

I tried this.

```
test_job:
  stage: test
  parallel: 3
  variables:
   CI_NODE_INDEX_ZERO: $( expr $CI_NODE_INDEX - 1 )
  script:
   - flutter test --total-shards $CI_NODE_TOTAL --shard-index $CI_NODE_INDEX_ZERO
```

The script still fails since the value of `$CI_NODE_INDEX_ZERO` is literal string `expr $CI_NODE_INDEX - 1` instead of `0` (or whatever integer value needed).

This actually works in my local terminal.

```
petrabarus@Petras-Air % CI_NODE_INDEX_ZERO=5
petrabarus@Petras-Air % CI_NODE_INDEX=5
petrabarus@Petras-Air % echo $CI_NODE_INDEX
5
petrabarus@Petras-Air % CI_NODE_INDEX_ZERO=$( expr $CI_NODE_INDEX - 1 )
petrabarus@Petras-Air % echo $CI_NODE_INDEX_ZERO
4
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Variables can only be literal values -- they are not *evaluated* in any way, like what happens in your bash shell.

If you want to use bash to evaluate and set variables for jobs, you can do that using a `dotenv` artifact.

```yaml
make_variables:
  stage: .pre  # run before all jobs
  script:
    # evaluate the value of a variable
    - DYNAMIC_VARIABLE=$(my-script)
    # Add the value to a dotenv file.
    - echo "DYNAMIC_VARIABLE=$DYNAMIC_VARIABLE" >> myvariables.env
  artifacts:
    reports:  # set the variables for subsequent jobs
      dotenv: myvariables.env

my_job:
  script:
    - echo "$DYNAMIC_VARIABLE"
```

Though the easier thing to do would be just to evaluate it directly in your script:

```yaml
  script:
   - SHARD_INDEX=$( expr $CI_NODE_INDEX - 1 )
   - flutter test --total-shards $CI_NODE_TOTAL --shard-index $SHARD_INDEX
```

Answer (score 0):

i think because VARIABLES can't read from Gitlab CI

please check it https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/

example

```
test_variable:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "$CI_JOB_STAGE"
```

please tried it

```
  script:
   - flutter test --total-shards "$CI_NODE_TOTAL" --shard-index "$CI_NODE_INDEX"
```